# Generate dynamic ads for Adwords?

Tags: google-ads-api

I was on Home Depot's website looking at some tools, and then I went to some random site and this video ad with all the products I was looking on Home Depot's website dynamically displayed on the video.  It was like wizardry.

But seriously, I don't even know where to start on how we'd do that.  I'm familiar with AdWords image ads, but don't know what to look for to research.  What are these types of ads even called?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: you are looking for dynamic image ads. You have to create a product feed for your store, use some tracking on your site and create the dynamic ad on AdWords. Take a look here https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3265299?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This is dynamic display ads and dynamic remarketing services of Google Adwords, with a specific feed with informations about your products (description, images, prices...) that is for the making ads.

For targeting previous visitors of your website you have to get a pixel code and put it in the pages of your website to track them.

all you need is here:

[Create dynamic display ads](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3265299?hl=en)

and here

[Use dynamic remarketing to show ads tailored to your site visitors](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3124536?hl=en)

Comment: While this may answer the question, [you should provide more of the essential parts of the answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259), and leave the links for reference.